# Ayuda con laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel

Estoy empezando a estudiar laravel 5.1, estoy entusiasmado con esto pero cuando creo un controller(contactoController)

```html
<?php 

namespace app\Http\Controllers;
use app\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class ContactoController extends Controller
{
 
    public function inicio()
    {
        return "esto es un controlador";
    }
}
```

en mi route hago lo siguiente

```
Route::get('contacto','ContactoController@inicio');
```

me sale el siguiente error:

```
Class 'app\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found
```

[image: Esta es la estructura de mis archivos]

Comment: Es una cosa común cuando se usan namespaces y pese a que todo parece estar correcto, que cuando tienes un error de X clase no encontrada sea por los namespaces. Laravel trae un namespace por defecto para todas sus clases, si se cambia debe hacerse con el comando artisan correspondiente. Cuando creemos controladores, modelos, etc. también es recomendable usar artisan para evitar futuros errores.

Answer (score 1):

alguna razon en particular por la que estes usando Laravel 5.1? (la ultima version estable con excelentes mejoras es laravel 5.2).

solo para estar seguro, cuando instalaste Laravel te salio la pagina principal (donde aparece el logo y unas Frases)? (para saber si te funciono la instalaciòn).

Si la instalaciòn es correcta intenta lo siguiente:

1) renombra tu controllador **ContactoController.php** a **Contactocontroller-copia.php**

2) Corre desde la consola **Artisan** para que te genere el Controllador.

Corriendo el comando:

```
php artisan make:controller ContactoController
```

3) en el archivos **routes.php**  incluye la ruta

```
Route::get('contacto','ContactoController@inicio');
```

4) contenido del controllador y el metodo inicio..

```
...
class ContactoController extends Controller
{

    public function inicio()
    {
        return "esto es un controlador";
    }
}...
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad.
Saludos...

Comment: Gracias Daniel Ferrans por responder estaba mal el nombre de mi  namespace lo hice como me dijo Shaz y funciono... y bueno utlizo la 5.1 por que tengo documentacion de esta version y videotutoriales.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que veo en la imagen que compartes, el namespace empieza por `cinema` y no por `app`.

Asumo que el error te sale al ir a la ruta `/contacto` ?

En resumen, el error debería estar en el namespace, así que verifica el namespace que tienes en composer.json:

```
"autoload": {
    ...
    "psr-4": {
        "cinema\\": "app/"
    },
```

O puedes cambiar el namespace con el comando:

```
php artisan app:name cinema
```

Entonces si el namespace base es `cinema`, el controlador contacto (y todos los demás controladores) debería quedar así:

```
<?php 

namespace cinema\Http\Controllers;

use Controller; // el controlador base está en el mismo namespace

class ContactoController extends Controller
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Hola Shaz efectivamente: era el naespace vea en mi conposer.json lo tengo de la siguiente manera: "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    } en el namespace los cambie por esto: namespace cinema\Http\Controllers;
use cinema\Http\Controllers\Controller y estaaa funcionoo.... Graciass

Comment: Que bueno que funcionó, si mi respuesta fue útil entonces puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Pensé que la respuesta correcta era la mía y no la otra ...

Comment: jejeje ya esta amigo...  Shaz, efectivamente con tu respuesta funcionooo perfecto, Gracias...

Comment: hola una pregunta que ventajas ves en laravel es util si estas haciendo una pagina en php?

Comment: @OmarAlami sin duda alguna, sin embargo deberías tener claras muchas cosas de OOP, SOLID y PHP antes de usarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Mirando tu código, me di cuenta que tu namespace esta mal

```
namespace app\Http\Controllers;
```

Deberia ser así

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

A laravel es case sensitive

Comment: PHP es "medio" case-sensitive, si Laravel lo es o no por completo, es por convención. No seguirla lo va a evitar que algo funcione.
Un enlace interesante sobre el tema (PHP): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33273941/php-case-sensitivity

Answer (score 0):

### Teoría

El problema radica en el namespaces , cuando Laravel da un error de :

```
Class 'app\Http\Controllers\Controller' not found
```

Suele ser un error de que en route estas redirigiendo incorrectamente la llamada a donde tiene que ir.

Los namespaces en Laravel son muy importantes son un estandar desde el [PSR4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) , donde comentan , junto con el [PSR2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/).

> Laravel follows the PSR-2 coding standard and the PSR-4 autoloading
>   standard.

[Fuente](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/contributions)

### Solución

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
class ContactoController extends Controller
{

    public function inicio()
    {
        return "esto es un controlador";
    }
}
```

Tu error se encuentra en :

```
namespace cinema\Http\Controllers;
```

Lógicamente si Laravel comienza en App\Http\Controllers , el cinema no lo coge.

Te aconsejo que uses el artisan de Laravel , que es una forma que te construye todos los modelos y los controladores de una forma estandar , como quiere que se usen , con el tiempo te fijarás como se hace y no necesitaras del comando , el comando sería :

```
php artisan make:[model|controller] --resource Evento

php artisan make:controller --resource ContactoController
```

[Link](https://github.com/jglantonio/gitNotes/blob/master/artisan.md) | [Fuente Oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/artisan)

- --resource lo que hace es crearte todas las cabeceras estándar que usa Laravel.

Esto lo tienes que ejecutar en el directorio raíz donde tienes instalado laravel , que es un nivel por debajo de la carpeta App que es donde comienza los Namespaces a escribir la dirección donde se encuentran.

### Curiosidad

Te pongo unas notas para que sepas la razón de los namespaces :

1. Los namespaces son necesarios para que no halla choques entre las clases , por ejemplo si tienes dos clases llamadas como en tu caso ContactoController , pues tengas crebaderos innecesarios de cabeza.
2. Otra de las razones es para definir de una forma perfecta donde está situada cada clase , para cuando hagas un use , en el código lo hagas a la clase que deseas.

#### PD

Espero haber ayudado , por medio de esta respuesta y no dudes en preguntar , no todos sabemos de todo , pero entre todos lo sabemos.